# Get domain name for pinterest api

Tags: api, pinterest

Currently I am working on pinterest api to get pin from my domain.
I am able to get access token by api.
Than I am making api call to get domain pin by using below :

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/domains/<domain>/search/pins?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN
```

But I am not sure what to put as `<domain>`.

How can I know what is my domain name in pinterest.

**Note : I have created app using 
http:developer.pinterest.com/manage**

**Also, there is not any provision of domain name over there, it should be your profile name or we may have to make some different process to get domain name.**

Comment: If you don't mind, how are you able to get access token ? I've tried all available methods but they seem to be dead or deprecated. Pinterest doesn't seem to support this anymore.

Comment: @Daniel: Click on following link and grant access. You will see your access token in the URL: https://www.pinterest.com/oauth/?consumer_id=1431594&response_type=token

Answer (score 1):

the value of domain is the domain of your website, in other words this link searches pinterest for everything already pinned from that website

`https://api.pinterest.com/v3/domains/mywebsite.com/search/pins?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`