# Is searching for pins using a keyword in Pinterest API deprecated?

Tags: pinterest

Since the beginning of this year (7 full months!), there has been a couple of questions about the search function in Pinterest API.

Example: I am getting the same response as our friend leonardo here: [Pinterest API search not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416624/pinterest-api-search-not-working-anymore)

Here, our friend Carl said the API now only serves for domain search purposes: [How to get search feed from Pinterest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507190/how-to-get-search-feed-from-pinterest-api) - that is a relatively fresh answer.

Thus, killing two birds with one stone, I would like to ask someone experienced with working with Pinterest API to share the current state of version 3 'global search' meaning if it is possible to execute a command like that nowadays:

```
file_get_contents('https://api.pinterest.com/v3/search/pins/?join=via_pinner,board,pinner&page_size=' . $number . '&query=' . $word . '&access_token=' . $key)
```

Plus, if impossible, what is the domain search Carl mentioned and can we use it for similar search purpose to look for pins containing a predefined keyword?

PS. [Get domain name for pinterest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731857/get-domain-name-for-pinterest-api) this is also pretty relevant.

Comment: Are there any updates? I am looking for the exact same feature but I don't find anything

Comment: Haven't checked lately, but my guess is it was deprecated and still is.

Comment: thank you for your response. It is a real shame

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to be looking for searching for pins using the API but it seems that their whole API has been revised and the global search function is not even available anymore (as far as I'm aware)